# Receive error when trying to use tern mode

Tags: javascript, tern

I have installed tern use npm and install tern.el from melpa. I put the path of tern.el in my init file as per instructions on the emacs section of the tern homepage. However when I enable tern mode and try to run a command such as jump to definition at point, I get the following error:

> Searching for program: no such file or directory, tern

What is the issue?

Comment: Have you installed tern, the external program?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to start the tern server from the command line.

Comment: I was having the same issue. I tried reinstalling tern and changing the path, but this didn't solved it. With --debug-init I found there was an issue in markdown-mode (which I load some lines before tern-mode). When I commented out the markdown-mode the message disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Tern was installed in /usr/local/bin, but emacs was not looking for it there. I added this to my init file to add /usr/local/bin to the path.

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
    (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```